# Execution failed for task ':jamsMusicPlayer:processDebugResources'. > java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am somewhat new to android programming. Currently I am working on an app which is forked from an open-source repository on GitHub. This app contains many dependencies in forms of module. When I try to Build the project in Android Studio, the build fails with the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':jamsMusicPlayer:processDebugResources'.> java.io.FileNotFoundException: M:\Redemption\JamsMusicPlayer\jamsMusicPlayer\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\JamsMusicPlayer\licensesdialoglibrary\unspecified\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

As I don't have enough reputation, I can't paste the screenshot here but
I think the file it is looking for is getting generated under M:\Redemption\JamsMusicPlayer\licensesdialoglibrary\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml

But I'm not able to figure out how to point to the right path from build.gradle or any other file:

Here's the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile = file('src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
        variant.outputs[0].processManifest.enabled=false }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
}
```

I tried to look for similar questions and answers already. But couldn't find any relevant solution to this problem. Any kind of help is much appreciated. Let me know if any other code is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats your open-source repository on GitHub link

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira https://github.com/psaravan/JamsMusicPlayer
actually this is the original repository.... I have not commited the changes that I have done on the forked repository.

Comment: i have no problem import it into my android studio..what IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm also using Android studio only... actually earlier it was working fine then I imported facebook sdk in the project... But there are no problems with facebook sdk... I'm getting the problem with licensedialoglibrary .